# Is it possible to embed a jar file in a Windows Powershell script?

Tags: java, windows, powershell, jar

When I have a jar(`hoge.jar`) file, and a unix shell script(`hoge.sh`) or a windows batch file(`hoge.bat`), I can obtain ones with the jar file like below:

```
cat hoge.sh hoge.jar >foo.sh
```

or

```
copy /b hoge.bat+hoge.jar foo.bat
```

Is there any way to do that with a powershell script (`hoge.ps1`)

```
copy /b hoge.ps1+hoge.jar foo.ps1
```

As for the `foo.ps1` obtained as above,

```
java -jar foo.ps1
```

does work, but the part of the powerscript never runs... (when used as the powerscript ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially store any file in a powershell script. Here is an excellent [article](https://www.loginvsi.com/login-vsi-blog/565-embed-external-files-in-powershell-scripts) that shows you how to do so with base 64 encoding.